# Conway's Game of Life Java Implementation

Tags: java, game-of-life

Keep state the same if it doesn't fall in the following conditions:

1. Change to 2 if there are exactly 2 ones in the neighbors
2. Change to 3 if there are more than 2 ones in the neighbors

It is also wrapping around so neighbors can be cyclic.

I wrote a basic structure and modularized it to individual functions. I wish to understand better coding techniques and how I can improve.

```
package code.Misc;
public class changeStateGame {
public static void main(String args[]){

    int current[][] = {
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
            {0,0,0,1,1,0,0},
            {0,0,1,1,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
    };
    int aux [][] = new int [current.length][current[0].length];

    for(int i=0;i<current.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<current[0].length;j++){
            aux[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Current State");
    printStateGame(current);
    System.out.println("Changed State");
    printStateGame(changeState(current,aux,0,aux[0].length));

}

public static void printStateGame(int a[][]){
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<a[0].length;j++){
            System.out.print(a[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}


public static int [][] changeState(int c[][],int a[][], int row, int col){

    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<a[0].length;j++){
            a[i][j]=checkNeighbors(c,i,j);
        }
    }
    return a;
}

public static int checkNeighbors(int a[][],int row,int col){

        int neighborCount = 0;
        for(int i=row-1;i<row+1;i++){
            for(int j=col-1;j<col+1;j++){

                        if (i < 0)
                            i = a.length - 1;
                        if (j < 0)
                            j = a[0].length - 1;
                        if (i == a.length)
                            i = 0;
                        if (j == a[0].length)
                            j = 0;
                        if(i==row){
                            if(j==col){
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        if(j==col){
                            if(i==row){
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        neighborCount += checkElement(a[i][j]);

            }
        }
    return modifyElement(a[row][col],neighborCount);
}
public static int checkElement(int a){
    if(a==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

public static int modifyElement(int a, int count){
    if(count<2){
        return a;
    }
    else if (count == 2){
        return 2;
    }
    else {
        return 3;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765" data-ss1465891299="1)*.

Answer (score 3):

#### Bug 1

Your neighbor counting loops are only iterating twice instead of three times, so you aren't counting neighbors to the right or below.

#### Bug 2

If you were to correct Bug 1, your program would infinite loop in `checkNeighbors` because you modify your loop variables inside the loop when they wrap around.  So for example, if `col` is the rightmost column, you will set `j` to 0 inside the loop which will cause the `j` loop to never terminate.

#### Bug 3

You sometimes set your array elements to 2 or 3.  But in Life, each array element should be 0 or 1 only.  Your `modifyElement` function is incorrect.

#### Dead code

These two blocks of code are identical, so the second is useless:

```
                    if(i==row){
                        if(j==col){
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    if(j==col){
                        if(i==row){
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
```

#### Unused arguments

The `changeState` function has two unused arguments: `row` and `col`.

Comment: For your last point, unused arguments, is there a possibility to tell the compiler to warn about unused method parameters? I'm working with eclipse, so if you can't tell your compiler directly, is there a good plugin for this?